# variables are undefined when parsing json with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I have having such a hard time getting my json variables out of my json that is retuned from my ajax call to my asp.net mvc controller class.  Here is my jquery ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("ReturnTotals", "Cart")',
        type: 'POST',
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function (jsonData) {
            var totals = $.parseJSON(jsonData);
            var cost = totals.cost;
            var qty = totals.qty;
            $("#totalCost").html(cost);
            $("#totalQty").html(qty);
            console.log(cost);
            console.log(qty);
            console.log($.parseJSON(jsonData));
        }
  });
```

My first 2 console.logs come back undefined.  And the third spits out

```
[Object { Key="cost", Value=109}, Object { Key="qty", Value=12}]
```

I have checked that line with jsonlint and it is well formed json.  For the line "var cost = totals.cost;" I have tried changing that to "var cost = totals["cost"];" and that didn't do anything.

Here is my server side function:

```
public string ReturnTotals()
    {
        CartSummaryModel cart = null;
        CartModel m = null;
        cart = (CartSummaryModel)cXML.cXML.DeserializeObject(Session["CARTSUMMARY"].ToString(), typeof(CartSummaryModel));
        Dictionary<string, double> totals = new Dictionary<string, double>();
        totals.Add("cost", cart.TotalCost);
        totals.Add("qty", cart.TotalQty);
        string totalString = cXML.cXML.SerializeJson( totals );
        return totalString;
    }
```

Comment: You are returning an array so to access it write `total[0].cost`

Comment: still returns 'undefined'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a default Json serialiser within assp.net mvc that you can use! In fact, I am not trying to discourage you from using your serializer but here is what works for me

```
     public JsonResult ReturnTotals()
     {
        CartSummaryModel cart = null;
        CartModel m = null;
        // cart = (CartSummaryModel) Session["CARTSUMMARY"] ;
         Dictionary<string, double> totals = new Dictionary<string, double>();
        totals.Add("cost", cart.TotalCost);
        totals.Add("qty", cart.TotalQty);
         return Json(totals,"text/json",JsonBehavour.AllowGet);
    }
```

And jQuery

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
      var url='@Url.Action("ReturnTotals", "Cart")';
      $.getJSON(url).done(function (jsonData) {
        var totals =[]||jsonData;
        var cost = totals.cost;
        var qty = totals.qty;
        $("#totalCost").html(cost);
        $("#totalQty").html(qty);
        console.log(cost);
        console.log(qty);
    });    

      });
```

Comment: This worked!  Something must have been wrong with the json I was passing using my old method.  Thank you much!